# How to authenticate users using only external system logins on the superset?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, apache-superset

How to authenticate users using only external system logins on the superset.
like this.
[image]

Is this possible?

I've never used Python at all, but I need to customize a superset.

The external login system is an oauth 2.0 based authentication system.

I want to authenticate using a token stored in local storage or using a login page provided by the authentication system of an external login system.

Is this possible?

If user authentication is not possible with an external authentication system alone, please explain how to use Superset's user authentication and external authentication system together.

Comment: Having `AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH` in `superset_config.py`is how you force the external login over the default one (`AUTH_DB`)

Comment: Good tutorial about JWT auth  https://laptrinhx.com/tutorial-how-to-integrate-superset-in-your-own-application-2272552308/

Answer (score 2):

You can begin with the official documentation on superset, although you'll probably have to tinker further to get it working:
https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset#custom-oauth2-configuration